# Visa for entering Panama

Tags: us-citizens

I am a U.S. passport holder and will arrive in Panama on August 19th 2019 and would like to stay until May 18, 2020 (9 months).

Do I need a visa? How long can I legally stay?

If I do, where can I find reliable information for the visa application?

Comment: What is the purpose of your visit? This sounds like such a long stay that it might be better handled at [Expats.SE].

Answer (score 1):

As you will stay more then 180 days, does not matter what is the reason, you will need a Visa.

> 180 Day Stay-Tourists can only remain in Panama for 180 days. This
>   rule is strictly enforced by Panamanian immigration. Travelers must
>   ensure that immigration officials place an entry stamp in their
>   passport.  For further information contact the Government of Panama
>   Migration Service.

Also, in this link, you could find more info about how you get a Visa.

It is important to highlight that Yellow fever vacination is mandatory in Panama

[Travel.State.Gov](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/international-travel/International-Travel-Country-Information-Pages/Panama.html)